# Saving Configuration with new appsetting value works locally but not on server (Webforms .Net)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config

I used some code that I found here to edit my web.config file and it works great on my local instance, but when I do this on the server, I get a null reference exception.  I have debugging code that tells me with ther configuration object is null (it's not) and also confirms that the web.config appsettings key that I am changing is being read correctly and then set to the new value, but when the save happens, it's triggering the exception, so I'm confused as to what exactly the null references is referring to:

```
 public static void AddOrUpdateAppSettings(string key, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var configFile = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            var settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;
            
            if (settings[key] == null)
            {
                settings.Add(key, value);
            }
            else
            {
                settings[key].Value = value;
            }
            configFile.Save();
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configFile.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
        }
        catch (ConfigurationErrorsException ex)
        {
            ErrorLog("AddOrUpdateAppSettings Error Info: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions? Anyway, modifying the web.config while the server is running is not something to even think to, You will have more success if you write the required data to another storage (json, xml, database?)

Comment: Modifications of web configuration will trigger an app pool restart and blow out your session,  and even trigger recompile of code. I would not modify web configuration at runtime unless it's a last resort.  Create a table with say one row and some columns for such settings

Comment: This is going to happen when we are putting the server into maintenance mode, and would be otherwise changing the web.config manually and disconnecting users, it's just a way to make this a bit less manual.  I assume I have permissions, but that is a good thought, maybe will see if I can change the permissions and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be the file permissions.  Once that was changed on the server, the save no longer threw the error.

Comment: Ok, as long as this is a one time one type of change, and not a "general" of on the fly changing web.config settings, you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a file permissions issue.  Once the web.config was given the permissions that the app pool identity was using, the config file gets saved as it should without errors.